# Remove special characters at end of row in unix file

Tags: sed

I have a csv file which has a delimiter `~@~~@~` and sometimes `~@~`. Same set of special characters `~@~~@~`(I dont know how many but `~@~~@~`*) appear at end of row which is a date field. So data in file is like

```
ABC~@~~@~TUV~@~~@~XYZ~@~PQR~@~13470~@~Management~@~Non-Employee IJK~@~T~@~12345~@~12345~@~abc@gmail.com~@~B~@~~@~~@~~@~6789~@~09/25/2017 11:31:22.000000~@~09/25/2017 3:22:03.000000~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~~@~\n
```

I need to remove the characters from Last Date field to End of line. 
I have tried `sed 's/~@~~@~~@~\n*//g' File name>Replacedfilename.txt`, but it retains one set of special characters at the end.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: If it *is* a CSV file with a special delimiter, then it seems more plausible that `~@~~@~` is an empty column (similar to `,,` in a CSV file with comma delimiters). If there are programs reading this file and you get rid of empty columns, are you sure that they are still going to work?

Answer (score 3):

```
... | sed 's/\(~@~\)*$//'
```

to remove any number of `~@~` at end of line (assuming of course that the `\n` in your sample represents the line-ending newline, and not a literal backslash and lowercase N.)

or in `sed`s that support `-E` for extended regular expressions:

```
... | sed -E 's/(~@~)+$//'
```

or you could use `awk -F'~@~'` and handle the fields you need to at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the above data is in file `f1.txt`.
We can use the sed command and remove every occurrence of `~@~~@~` and `~@~`.
I've replaced it with a blank space.

```
sed -e 's/~@~~@~/#/g;s/~@~/#/g;s/# */ /g' f1.txt > output.txt
```

Result

```
ABC TUV XYZ PQR 13470 Management Non-Employee IJK T 12345 12345 abc@gmail.com B  6789 09/25/2017 11:31:22.000000 09/25/2017 3:22:03.000000
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cat file |sed 's/~@~~@~~@~//g' |sed 's/~@~$//'
```

the first sed remove the string `~@~~@~` and the second sed remove the last `~@~`

Comment: it doesn't remove the ~@~ delimiters, the first sed removes the string ~@~~@~ and the second removes the ~@~ that remains at the end of the line

Comment: There's a pipe missing (although it would be better to get rid of the `cat` altogether). Also as @ilkkachu points out, you are getting rid of things in the middle of the line and you are only getting rid of a single delimiter at the end of the line.

Comment: Sorry, I mean it removes the `~@~~@~`'s from the middle of the line, as in the beginning of the sample, here: `ABC~@~~@~TUV`. Not the single `~@~`'s, of course.

Comment: @Nick, at EOL, it works, since the first one removes all doubled `~@~`'s, and the second removes the single one potentially left over at the end.

Comment: I modified my answer taking account the comments, I piut the missing pipe and naow the first sed remove the string ~@~~@~~@~, the second sed removes the ~@~ at the end of the line

Comment: @user3333911, well, that will still remove the `~@~`'s in the middle, if some input happens to have two adjacent empty columns. That's not really a robust feature if the aim is to only remove the ones at the end of line. Now it will also leave one `~@~` in the end if their count is one less than a multiple of three (i.e. 3n + 2)